# Apply() for data.frame, using data.frame column text as function name

Tags: r

I have this data:

```
v <- c('a1','ABC','bc','A',NA,'BA','CU','ND')

st_map <- data.frame('Qid'=paste0("Q",1:4),
       'Function'=c('single_choice_percentage','multiple_choice_percentage','none','none'))

st_data <- data.frame('Q1'=sample(v,5),
                   'Q2'=sample(v,5),
                   'Q3'=sample(v,5),
                   'Q4'=sample(v,5))
```

I have created different functions named (single_choice_percentage, multiple_choice_percentage, etc.) and I want to pass the Qid-function combinations defined in st_map to data storaged in st_data.

My function looks like this although I imagine it should change in order to do what I want.

```
single_choice_percentage <- function(q_n){
  
  df <- st_data %>% select(q_n) %>% drop_na();df
  
  
  # Frequency table
  
  ft <<- df %>% group_by(across(.cols = everything())) %>% 
    summarise(n=n()) %>%  filter(!is.na(q_n)) %>%  #TO DO, pass q_n as argument
    mutate(tot=sum(n),share=(n/sum(n))*100)
  return(ft)}
```

I am attempting something like

```
lapply(st_map[,1],get(st_map[,3]))
```

Of course with little success. Can you help?

Comment: could you explain a little bit, what you are trying to do, e.g. what should the `get`function should do in the `lapply`?

Comment: I am trying to use the column fuction, as the actual function to be applied. You can see that one of the choices has the same name as the function created.